# Why will the stones be in Hell?

Tags: quran

It is said that men and stones will be in Hell. But why the stone? What has it done? It is in chapter 2, verse 24 of the Quran.

Comment: [Sahih International]
"But if you do not - and you will never be able to - then fear the Fire, whose fuel is men and stones, prepared for the disbelievers." Doesn't necessarily mean that the stones are being punished.

Comment: So is it also meant that humans will be punished? I have read an incident of Boojorgo where a stone was crying because of knowing this ayah. Then Allah had forgiven it. So?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking? Have you actually read the preceding and following ayahs?

Comment: Why do you think stones are being punished because they are fuel of hell?  What makes you think stones have "feelings"?

Comment: I have read an event of buzurgo, where a stone was crying by flowing water, in surah baqarah, Allah have said that , some stones. . . .{baqara-ayah-74}. So, I think that stones are alive. I  have thought that why they will be punished like human!